# POST HTTP para Nota Fiscal

Tags: c#, web-service, soap, nfe

Caros, Boa Tarde.
Estou precisando enviar um XML via post para a função do webservice da Nota Fiscal Paulistana. Porém, o XML está correto, apenas retorna uma mensagem que é muito genérica, então não tem muito o que dizer a vocês. Apenas gostaria que verificassem se a chamada que estou fazendo está correta, ou se tem algo errado. Segue abaixo o código.

```
public string RequestWebService(string wsURL, string param, string action, X509Certificate2 certificado)
        {
            Uri urlpost = new Uri(wsURL);
            HttpWebRequest httpPostConsultaNFe = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlpost);

            string postConsultaComParametros = param;
            byte[] buffer2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postConsultaComParametros);

            httpPostConsultaNFe.CookieContainer = cookies;
            httpPostConsultaNFe.Timeout = 300000;
            httpPostConsultaNFe.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8; action=" + action;
            httpPostConsultaNFe.Method = "POST";
            httpPostConsultaNFe.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);
            httpPostConsultaNFe.ContentLength = buffer2.Length;

            Stream PostData = httpPostConsultaNFe.GetRequestStream();
            PostData.Write(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length);
            PostData.Close();

            HttpWebResponse responsePost = (HttpWebResponse)httpPostConsultaNFe.GetResponse();
            Stream istreamPost = responsePost.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader strRespostaUrlConsultaNFe = new StreamReader(istreamPost, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

            return strRespostaUrlConsultaNFe.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Podem me ajudar, por gentileza?

Obrigado.